# I want to buy a domain name and setup my own email server; Any good tutorials?

Tags: iis-7, email-server

I want to buy a domain name, create my website and create an email server. I have IIS7 with windows 7. Can anyone point me to a good tutorial on the internet?

I know the website hosting thing, but I am not getting any email server hosting tutorial.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Consider using Google Apps Standard edition http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html

Comment: Seriously... Running a web server is great and all, but you'll never beat the features you get from running Google apps for you domain. Unless you have some specific reason why you need your own email server I highly suggest using Google apps for email.

Comment: +1: setting up an MTA is not an easy task.

Comment: +1 don't.  http://serverfault.com/questions/125467/how-difficult-is-it-to-setup-a-mailserver/125584#125584

Answer (score 0):

You will need email server software. You will also need to know what ports your ISP blocks and if it's even against the rules of your ISP to host a service like that on your home network.

As for a tutorial, look at [hmailserver](http://www.hmailserver.com/) and read the tutorials. [It's fairly simple](http://www.ehow.com/how_5002684_set-up-email-server.html). Elephants are best eaten one bite at a time... and setting up an email server is no elephant. A side of beef, maybe.

FYI, you'll probably need to have a SMTP redirection service or an SMTP smarthost to send outbound mail since you won't be able to edit your own [RDNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup). Your ISP may have a SMTP relay. Check their website for more info. You could also use some place like DynDNS or [Roller Network](http://rollernet.us/) for incoming and outgoing mail server and redirection. I prefer Roller Network, but I'm a geek.

If you use an SMTP relay (note: not an OPEN relay) then you will also avoid having to set up an SPF record. You can also edit your firewall to only accept incoming and outgoing SMTP traffic from your designated incoming and outgoing upstream servers.

There you are. A crash course in making your own email server. Tip your waitresses.

Comment: @user42121, an upvote would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get a mail server set up and running relatively easily, but one thing that will cause you headaches is spam. While there are a lot of free tools around to help combat spam, I second going the Google Apps route for hosting your mail (can't beat the price: FREE, and their spam filtering is top-notch) and instead focus on setting up and running your webserver. Exchange is hairy and the commercial anti-spam solutions are expensive.

Is there a strong reason you want to set up a mail server? Or is it just to practice?

Comment: just to practice